# Plotting Smith and Sandwell global seafloor topography grids in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, convert, topography, bathymetry

Does anybody have any experience with plotting Smith & Sandwell 2-minute Mercator-projected grids in ArcGIS?

I've downloaded one in two formats: ers and img. I've found tools for processing .img data called Generic Mapping Tools (GMT).

Within this library there are commands which allow manipulating img grids, which is [just what I need](http://tabs2.gerg.tamu.edu/gmt/GMT_Docs/node150.html).

This example uses the img2grd command which I can't find within the GMT library.

The only tool I found so far was img2mercgrd but it wasn't successful.

How can I process this dataset to GIS format?

Comment: Exactly how did img2mercgrd fail?

Answer (score 2):

Try to make use of the utility [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid input.img output.grd
```

Comment: SaultDon,Thanks for your suggestion. I actually managed after all to get the .grd file out through Cygwin library. However the problem is with processing with the actual dataset - it is in a spherical Mercator projection which is tricky to work out in ArcGIS. I work with topo11.1 img (+.ers) dataset version. So the next step is to work it up into a correctly projected and valid GIS format. Any suggestions??? Many thanks!

Comment: So you are looking to reproject the data? Try searching the stackexchange for those questions (keywords: project spherical mercator - for example) and see if someone has a similar case to yours. If not, you may be able to post another question.